# Function to update values and melt columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table that is currently in a wide format and very large (upwards of 20,000+ rows). The data is currently formatted in a way that there are about 20-30 columns with values of 0 or 1 that I need to combine into one column. I could use `melt` or `do.call(paste())` but I can't figure out a way to then determine which column the 0s and 1s came from. My current process, which works fine, is to update each column individually so that any 1s become the same string as the name of that column and then use `do.call(paste())` to merge all those columns into one. I feel like there has to be a more elegant way to go through this process but I can not come up with anything. Is there a better way than my current method (see below for current method)?

Very scaled down data.table:

```
dput(head(photos01a))
structure(list(photo_name = c("BENT-5023-2-150927-CHECK1 (1).JPG", 
"BENT-5023-2-150927-CHECK1 (10).JPG", "BENT-5023-2-150927-CHECK1 (100).JPG", 
"BENT-5023-2-150927-CHECK1 (101).JPG", "BENT-5023-2-150927-CHECK1 (102).JPG", 
"BENT-5023-2-150927-CHECK1 (103).JPG"), BAAS = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), BIRD = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), CADO = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
CAFA = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), CALA = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), CALL = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), CEEL = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_), Crew = c("CREW", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000012d1fe71ef0>)
```

Current method:

```
# Adjust the species columns so they can be combined into one column
  photos01a[BAAS == 1, BAAS := "BAAS"]
  photos01a[BIRD == 1, BIRD := "BIRD"] 
  photos01a[CADO == 1, CADO := "CADO"] 
  photos01a[CAFA == 1, CAFA := "CAFA"]
  photos01a[CALA == 1, CALA := "CALA"]
  photos01a[CALL == 1, CALL := "CALL"] 
  photos01a[CEEL == 1, CEEL := "CEEL"] 
  photos01a[Crew == 1, Crew := "CREW"] 

# Create a list of all the species columns
  species_cols <- c("BAAS", "BIRD", "CADO", "CAFA", "CALA", "CALL", "CEEL", "Crew")
  
# Merge the species columns into one column, any photos that have more then one species tagged will have the 4 letter codes pushed together (i.e. TASP and TADO become TASPTADO)
photos01a[, "org_species" := .(col_test = do.call(paste, c(replace(.SD, is.na(.SD), ""), sep = ""))), .SDcols = species_cols]
# Separate out species for photos with multiple tags
photos01a[, "species_1" := substr(org_species, 1, 4)]
photos01a[nchar(org_species) > 4, "species_2" := substr(org_species, 5, 8)]
photos01a[nchar(org_species) > 8, "species_3" := substr(org_species, 9, nchar(org_species))]
# Bring those seperate species back into one column and get rid of unneeded columns
photos01 <- photos01a %>% 
    melt(measure.vars = c("species_1", "species_2", "species_3"),# Pivot table so there 
         value.name = "species",                                 # is only one species column, 
         value.factor = TRUE,                                    # and photos with 2 tags are 
         variable.name = "tag_order",                            # duplicated with one tag in each
         variable.factor = TRUE,
         na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Are you sure you have shared the correct data? There are no 1/0 values in it.

Comment: Sorry I think I did share the wrong version. The data is the same, any NA values are the 0s and other values are the 1s. This is what I'd like the data to end up like.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you provided an intermediate object as your data, so your example is not actually reproducible.

I have edited the data so it can be more illustrative.

**Data**

```
                            photo_name BAAS BIRD CADO CAFA CALA CALL CEEL Crew
1:   BENT-5023-2-150927-CHECK1 (1).JPG    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    1
2:  BENT-5023-2-150927-CHECK1 (10).JPG   NA    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
3: BENT-5023-2-150927-CHECK1 (100).JPG   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
4: BENT-5023-2-150927-CHECK1 (101).JPG   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
5: BENT-5023-2-150927-CHECK1 (102).JPG   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
6: BENT-5023-2-150927-CHECK1 (103).JPG   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

I have a solution with dplyr, which relies basically on `replace` and `tidyr::unite`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% mutate(across(BAAS:Crew, ~replace(.x, .x==1, deparse(substitute(.x))))) %>%
        unite(BAAS:Crew, col=new, na.rm=TRUE, sep="")

                            photo_name      new
1:   BENT-5023-2-150927-CHECK1 (1).JPG BAASCrew
2:  BENT-5023-2-150927-CHECK1 (10).JPG     BIRD
3: BENT-5023-2-150927-CHECK1 (100).JPG         
4: BENT-5023-2-150927-CHECK1 (101).JPG         
5: BENT-5023-2-150927-CHECK1 (102).JPG         
6: BENT-5023-2-150927-CHECK1 (103).JPG
```

**dput for the data:**

```
structure(list(photo_name = c("BENT-5023-2-150927-CHECK1 (1).JPG", 
"BENT-5023-2-150927-CHECK1 (10).JPG", "BENT-5023-2-150927-CHECK1 (100).JPG", 
"BENT-5023-2-150927-CHECK1 (101).JPG", "BENT-5023-2-150927-CHECK1 (102).JPG", 
"BENT-5023-2-150927-CHECK1 (103).JPG"), BAAS = c(1, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), BIRD = c(NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA), CADO = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), CAFA = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), CALA = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), CALL = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), CEEL = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Crew = c(1, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```